# React radio input not checking

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple form which has a couple of radio buttons that aren't checking. Each button has a change event attached, but still nothing changes. What can I do to not only capture their data, but signify that the input is selected?

**The form**

```
FormComponent = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    label: React.PropTypes.string,
    onChange: React.PropTypes.func
  },

  handleEvent(e) {
    let {onChange} = this.props;
    console.log(e);
  },

  render() {
    const {label} = this.props;
    return (
      <form className="lm-widget__form lm-flex-row">
        <fieldset className="lm-flex-row__column lm-h-flex-50">
          <RadioSet group='radio-group'
                    label={label}
                    radios={[
                      {
                        value: 'new',
                        checked: true,
                        changeEvent: this.handleEvent,
                        text: 'radio one'
                      },
                      {
                        value: 'old',
                        checked: false,
                        changeEvent: this.handleEvent,
                        text: 'radio two'
                      }
                    ]}
          />
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    )
  }

});
```

**The radio buttons**

```
RadioSet = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    group: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    label: React.PropTypes.string,
    radios: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(
      React.PropTypes.shape({
        value: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        checked: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        changeEvent: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        text: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
      })
    ).isRequired
  },

  render: function () {
    const {group, label, radios} = this.props;
    const self = this;

    if (label) {
      return(
        <div className="lm-widget-form__label">
          <div className="small">{label}</div>
          <div className="segment-controls">
            {radios.map(function(radio, i){
              return (
                <div key={i} className="segment-controls__group-item">
                  <input type="radio"
                          name={self.props.group}
                          className="segment-controls__button"
                          id={`radio-${i}`}
                          value={radio.value}
                          checked={radio.checked}
                          onChange={radio.changeEvent}
                  />

                  <label htmlFor={`radio-${i}`}
                         className="segment-controls__label">

                       <span className="segment-controls__label-text">
                             {radio.text}
                       </span>

                  </label>
                </div>
              );
            })
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
    else {
      return (
        <div className="segment-controls">
          {this.props.radios.map(function(radio, i){
            return (
              <div key={radio.value} className="segment-controls__group-item">
                <input type="radio"
                        name={self.props.group}
                        className="segment-controls__button"
                        id={`radio-${i}`}
                        value={radio.value}
                        checked={radio.checked}
                        onChange={radio.changeEvent}
                />

                <label htmlFor={`radio-${i}`}
                       className="segment-controls__label">

                     <span className="segment-controls__label-text">
                           {radio.text}
                     </span>

                </label>
              </div>
            );
          })
          }
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You are currently always passing the same value to `checked`:  `checked: true`. The button value should probably be read from the state of the component instead. I recommend to read https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html, especially about controlled components.

Comment: Thanks, I've been reading over that and for some reason it's just not clicking with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue is that you're telling the first radio button it's checked every time by passing `true` to it.

If we change your first bit of code to use `setState` this should work.

```
FormComponent = React.createClass({

  getInitialState() {
      return {
          checkedIndex: 0
      };
  },

  propTypes: {
    label: React.PropTypes.string,
    onChange: React.PropTypes.func
  },

  handleEvent(index, e) {
    this.setState({
        checkedIndex: index
    });
    let {onChange} = this.props;
    console.log(e);
  },

  render() {
    const {label} = this.props;
    const radios = [
                      {
                        value: 'new',
                        checked: false,
                        changeEvent: this.handleEvent.bind(this, 0),
                        text: 'radio one'
                      },
                      {
                        value: 'old',
                        checked: false,
                        changeEvent: this.handleEvent.bind(this, 1),
                        text: 'radio two'
                      }
                    ];
    radios[this.state.checkedIndex].checked = true;
    return (
      <form className="lm-widget__form lm-flex-row">
        <fieldset className="lm-flex-row__column lm-h-flex-50">
          <RadioSet group='radio-group'
                    label={label}
                    radios={radios}
          />
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    )
  }

});
```

Also note we are using `bind` to maintain the `this` context of `handleEvent` and to pass in the proper index.